# Creating E commerce using Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, e-commerce

I want to build an E-commerce system (intermediate scale to big scale) and have to choose a platform to use for developement. In general we use Codeigniter sometimes Angular.

But I want to try a new platform using Angular 2 to build this system. However our team still looks for plus and minus in many aspects if we use Angular especially concerning security and speed load each page using Credit Card and SEO.

Would you like to give me some suggestion to choose the best platform (not Wordpress, Magento, other CMS) to build an E-commerce site?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you checkout [Moltin](http://moltin.com) with either Angular2 or ReactJS. Moltin is a API platform as a service. very flexible to us and it trending solution for any type of UI Design you have and want to use. They also have cross platform iOS, Andriod, Web SDK. Get you running in no time.. I am working on a project with Angular2 and Moltin.